# Android - continuous socket write

Tags: android, sockets, client-server, broken-pipe

I'm working on an application that receives data from a bluetooth sensor, and I need to pass that data to a server socket running on a local machine. The data received is about 40 messages per second.

First, first i tried to solve it by using a seprate AsyncTask for each write, opening the socket, writing the data and closing the socket, and it worked fine, but raised some perfomance issues, so i had to find another solution.

I wrote a service that keeps the socket connection alive, but when I try to write data to the socket, I keep getting a broken pipe exception for each write.

Here's the code for the service:

```
public class SocketService extends Service {
public static final String SERVERIP = "10.64.64.197";
public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
private DataOutputStream out;
private Socket socket;

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    SocketService getService() {
        return SocketService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Runnable connect = new connectSocket();
    new Thread(connect).start();
}

public void sendMessage(byte[] message) {
    try {
        out.write(message);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class connectSocket implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.e("connectSocket", "Connecting...");
            socket = new Socket(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);
            try {
                out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                Log.e("connectSocket", "Done.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("connectSocket", "Error", e);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("connectSocket", "Error", e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    socket = null;
}
```

And the code where I call the sendMessage method:

```
if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE)) {
    final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);
    try {
        mSocketService.sendMessage(txValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "data_available");
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on this for a while now, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: broken pipe exception usually indicates that socket has been closed from the other party. Are you sure communication went through ?

Comment: the first few messages always go through (1-2 usually), but after that, nothing, just broken pipe exception.

Comment: yeah it means you server is closing sockets connections.